# AspNet Core Display multiple records as one row with multiple columns in table

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm having trouble with table view.

I want my table to look like this one

```
  Name  | Test1 | Test2 | Test3  
================================
Anna    | 70    |   51  |  90
================================
Jack    | 56    |   77  |  82
================================
```

Now I have

```
  Name  | Grade |   Test   | 
================================
Anna    | 70    |   Test1  | 
================================
Anna    | 51    |   Test2  | 
================================
Anna    | 90    |   Test3  | 
================================
Jack    | 56    |   Test1  | 
================================
Jack    | 77    |   Test2  | 
================================
Jack    | 82    |   Test3  | 
================================
```

The number of tests is dynamic.
Is there any way to do this? Couldn't find anything.
Should I create another model? Or it could be solved by editing View?

Model

```
public class StudentsWork
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdStudentsWork { get; set; }
        public int? Grade { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
        public int Student_id { get; set; }
        public int Course_id { get; set; }
        public int Test_id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Student_id")]
        public Student StudentId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Course_id")]
        public Course CourseId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Test_id")]
        public Test TestId { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Group(int? id,int id_group)
        {
            var group = await _context.StudentsWork
                .Include(p => p.StudentId)
                .ThenInclude(p => p.GroupId)
                .Include(p => p.CourseId)
                .Include(p => p.TestId)
                .Where(c => c.Course_id == id && c.StudentId.Group_id == id_group)
                .ToListAsync();       
            return View(group);
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by `StudentId` and select a dictionary for each group to get test name and grade :

```
var query = db.StudentsWork.Include(p => p.StudentId)
.Include(p => p.CourseId)
.Include(p => p.TestId)
.GroupBy(c => c.StudentId)
.Select(g => new
{
    StudentName=g.Key.Name,

    TestGrade = g.ToDictionary(t => t.TestId.Name, t => t.Grade)
});

var result = query.ToList();
```

[image]